# Retrieve selected fields with Spring Data Elasticsearch by using fields option, not by source filtering

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch, opensearch

We're trying to migrate our Opensearch cluster to Elasticsearch.

**We've been using Spring Data Elasticsearch with OpenSearch and using fields option to retrieve selected fields.**
(BaseQueryBuilder#withFields along with BaseQueryBuilder#withSourceFilter)

Sample code:

```
    NativeSearchQueryBuilder queryBuilder =
        new NativeSearchQueryBuilder().withQuery(query)
                                      .withFields("someId")
                                      .withSourceFilter(new FetchSourceFilter(new String[] {}, new String[] {"*"}));
```

This was working with Spring Data 4.2.X and Opensearch 1.2.4.

However, with Spring Data 4.4.X and Elasticsearch 8.3, SearchHit's content field does not contain given fields.

What I want to achieve is similar to this query:

```
GET some_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "fields": [
    "someId"
  ],
  "_source": false
}
```

---

**Tried attempts:**

1.

```
    NativeSearchQueryBuilder queryBuilder =
        new NativeSearchQueryBuilder().withQuery(query)
                                      .withFields("someId");
```

**No luck, it's as if this parameter is ignored, returns all the fields in documents.**

2.

```
    NativeSearchQueryBuilder queryBuilder =
        new NativeSearchQueryBuilder().withQuery(query)
                                      .withSourceFilter(new FetchSourceFilter(new String[] {"someId"}, null))
```

**It works.** However, in official ES documentation, [it states that](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-fields.html#field-retrieval-methods):

> **Using fields is typically better**
>
> These options are usually not required. Using the fields option is
> typically the better choice, unless you absolutely need to force
> loading a stored or docvalue_fields.

**So is it worse that using source filtering instead of fields option performance wise?**

**Is it possible to achieve disabling source and getting selected fields by fields option with Spring Data Elasticsearch?**

If it's not possible we consider to use SearchSourceBuilder instead of Spring Data's NativeSearchQueryBuilder.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce that. I just ran a sample application (set up using Spring Boot 2.7.0 with Spring Data
Elasticsearch 4.4.2 and an Elasticsearch instance version 8.3.3).

My test entity class is named `Foo` and the property in this object I use is `moreText`.
The code to send the request:

```java
var query=new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
    .withQuery(matchAllQuery())
    .withFields("moreText")
    .withSourceFilter(new FetchSourceFilter(new String[]{},new String[]{"*"}))
    .build();

    return operations.search(query, Foo.class);
```

I trace the calls to Elasticsearch with an intercepting proxy and see that this creates the following call:

```json
{
    "from": 0,
    "size": 10,
    "query": {
        "match_all": {
            "boost": 1.0
        }
    },
    "version": true,
    "explain": false,
    "_source": {
        "includes": [],
        "excludes": [
            "*"
        ]
    },
    "fields": [
        {
            "field": "more-text"
        }
    ]
}
```

The returned answer is:

```json
{
    "took": 93,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 1,
        "successful": 1,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 1,
            "relation": "eq"
        },
        "max_score": 1.0,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "foo",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "42",
                "_version": 1,
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {},
                "fields": {
                    "more-text": [
                        "More text!"
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The returned answer is exactly what is wanted. This is mapped into the Java entity, see this screenshot from the debugger:

[image]

As you can see, Spring Data Elasticsearch also manage if the name of the entitys property (`moreText`) is different from the field name in Elasticsearch (`more-text`).

So there must be something different in your setup. Could it be that in your mapping the `_source` is disabled (or some fields?), see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-source-field.html#disable-source-field

Can you provide a minimal sample application on Github that reproduces this behaviour?